# Photos section of OSX Yosemite file picker dialog out of date -- any way to force an update?

Tags: macos, photos.app

On my MacBook Pro running 10.10.4, just now, I wanted to upload an image to a website that I was browsing in Safari, so I clicked an upload field and got the usual dropdown Finder dialog. I choose "Photos" in the left sidebar to browse my Photos Library.

I open the "Moments" section to look for a photo I took yesterday. The photo's not there. In fact, the whole "moment", comprising 16 photos, is missing. I open the Photos app to confirm that the moment is on my laptop, and it is.

So for some reason the Finder dialog lags behind the Photos app. Is there any way to "kick" it and prompt it to update? Or better yet, to eliminate the delay completely?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. It may seem that the fact that I have my Photos library on an external drive causes it.

In Apple Photos, I saw in the Preferences dialog (tab General) a button "use as System library". Pushing that solved my issue.